# Import User profiles from AD not working

Tags: 2010, active-directory, user-profile-service, profile-sync, synchronisation

I intend to import user profiles from AD to SharePoint 2010 but I can't do it. See the process that I am following below:

When I got to User Profile Service Application -> Configure Synchronization Connections-> Create New Connection -> I can connect to AD using credentials and Forest Name -> Populate Containers even populate different OU in AD -> When I select one OU in AD -> After that I run Incremental/Full Import, it didn't import anything.

I double checked with MIIS Client but only Success is showing up, but I don't see any profiles data being showing up.

**The source which solved the issue:**
http://sharepoint-2010-world.blogspot.se/2011/02/replication-access-was-denied-error.html

Comment: Grant Replicate Directory Changes permission on a domain are required: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh296982.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like 'Replicating Directory Changes' permissions was not appropriately applied to your sync account.  I aggree with Seb, you should use the [Harbar guide](http://harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx).

Comment: Yeah you are right: http://sharepoint-2010-world.blogspot.se/2011/02/replication-access-was-denied-error.html

Answer (score 0):

does the user profile synchronization services is started?

Also, it may take some times to populate the user profiles.

Comment: Yes, it is started

Comment: I double checked with MIIS Client but only Success is showing up, but I don't see any profiles data being showing up.

Comment: Did you use the harbar guide to implement this?
http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx